# What word or phrase means the opposite of "white space"?

Tags: terminology

I'm currently writing some C# extension methods dealing with string parsing, and I like to be terse yet descriptive and accurate in my method names.

Question: Is there a good word or phrase that describes the opposite of white space?

To be clear, this set of characters are visible and would consume ink if printed on paper.  But I don't care to use terms related to ink, paper, or printing, nor do I want to assume any particular colors.

VisibleCharacters seems the most technically accurate but a bit long.

NonWhiteSpace seems like a double negative to me. I'd rather deal in what something IS, rather than what it IS NOT.

Thanks.

Comment: printable charactres

Comment: I believe Printable Charaacters is fairly commonly used.  This term would traditionally exclude control characters, but may work well for your purposes.

Comment: Printable is certainly the traditional word. But it seems odd when going digital and moving away from paper. There's probably going to be a day when nothing gets printed anymore. I'm fairly certain I'm way over-thinking this. Just hoping someone knows a term that I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went with the word "glyph", and called my function HasGlyph.

It seems to correctly cover characters which are readable, visible and printable; but does not refer to white-space or control characters. It doesn't assume that the character is being displayed graphically or is being printed. It doesn't assume any color. It also covers letters, numbers, and shapes.

Plus, its also a very short name.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph

In case you're curious, my extension method:

```
public static bool HasGlyph(this string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(value)) return false;
    // TODO: Not 100% sure if the opposite of the IsNullOrWhitespace method covers what I want, but its good enough until I find out otherwise.
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* mean everything but whitespace, I would suggest using the term `non-whitespace character`. This is also what the Perl documentation does for the `\S` character class, see the [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) and [`perlrecharclass`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html) manual pages (search for `\S`).

This term

- is more accurate than `non-blank` (with `blank` usually referring to the character with ASCII code 32)
- does not imply whitespace being not printable

Note that this definition includes characters like `NUL` or `ESC` that are neither whitespace (because they do not actually insert any kind of space) nor graphic / printable. So maybe you really want to limit yourself to `graphic` characters.

Comment: I gave this an up-vote because when you start dealing with Unicode characters, it gets more complicated and I don't think `glyph` will hold up. `non-whitespace` is simple, clear in meaning, covers Unicode, doesn't require any second guessing and doesn't require looking up a definition to be certain.

Comment: Do you have an example in regards to the Unicode issue? Like a character example?

Answer (score 1):

According to what you can find in the Unix manuals (`man isspace`), you may call them “printable characters” or “graphic characters”:

```
   isspace()
          checks for white-space characters.  In the "C" and "POSIX" locales,
          these are: space, form-feed ('\f'), newline ('\n'), carriage return ('\r'),
          horizontal tab ('\t'), and vertical tab ('\v').

   isgraph()
          checks for any printable character except space.
```

Comment: Interesting that your excerpt actually uses the term `printable character`.

Comment: Your excerpt suggests that graphic and printable characters _include_ space (otherwise it wouldn't have to state `except space`). Apart from that, I would consider whitespace printable because without it, every output looks different.